# Fetching fuel price from google map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to retrieve fuel prices from all nearby stations. I am using `PlacesApi`. While it retrieves all the station information like location, address, ratings, etc it doesn't return the fuel price info. After a bit of searching I found that map api doesn't return fuel api. Is there any work around to get this info?

This is what I have implemented so far.

```
List<PlaceDetails> list = new ArrayList<>();

GeocodingResult[] geocodingResults = new GeocodingResult[0];
try {
    geocodingResults = GeocodingApi.geocode(context,"Dallas").await();
    if (geocodingResults.length > 0) {
        LatLng location = geocodingResults[0].geometry.location;

        // Perform the Places API request to get the gas stations in Dallas
        PlacesSearchResponse searchResponse = PlacesApi.nearbySearchQuery(context, location)
                .radius(20000) // Specify the search radius in meters (adjust as needed)
                .type(PlaceType.GAS_STATION) // Search for gas stations
                .await();


        // Iterate through the results and print the gas station names
        for (PlacesSearchResult result : searchResponse.results) {
            PlaceDetails placeDetails = PlacesApi.placeDetails(context, result.placeId).awaitIgnoreError();
            list.add(placeDetails);
            System.out.println(result.name);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unable to geocode Dallas.");
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

The `placeDetails` obj contains all the info except fuel info.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### No plans of adding `Fuel Prices` data in Places API at the moment

First of all, Google Maps (App) and Google Maps (API) are different platforms, so we should set our expectation that they have different features and functionalities.

Now with regards to adding **Fuel Prices** data in **Places API**, there was a **Feature Request** filed 3 years ago (July, 2020) in relation to this and you can see it here in this link:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162155201

Please note that the Issue Tracker entry above is the authoritative source for public information regarding the aforementioned issue, and all publicly-relevant updates is posted there.

With that said, it looks like Google has no plans at the moment in adding this feature to the Places API, since they marked it as ***Won't Fix (Infeasible)*** and said this:

> We have reviewed your request and we don't have plans to implement
> this feature for Places API at the moment. Please do note that Places
> API aims to provide common details for the different supported
> `place_types` and not specific to `gas_stations` only.

If you are  still interested with this feature, you can just upvote the Feature Request in the link I provided and comment there your use case to help with reconsideration.

I hope this information helped!

Answer (score 0):

Google Places API (New) has fuel prices now. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/reference/rest/v1/places#fuelprice